# Problema codigo en C se cierra la ejecucion

Tags: c++, c

tengo un problema urgente con un codigo en C, tengo que pasar de un archivo a una lista LSE, hice el algoritmo pero cuando ejecuto la funcion el programa se cierra, el tipo que tengo es este registro:

```
enum generos {Action, Comedy, Adventure, Drama, Horror, SciFi, Fantasy, Animation};
typedef enum {Color, BW}Tcolor;
typedef struct{
char id[15];
char titulo[100];
char director[35];
enum generos genero;
char likes[10];
char cantidad_votantes[10];
char voto_promedio[5];
char anio[4];
char costo[15];
Tcolor color;
}Movie;
```

Esta es la accion que pasa del archivo a la lista:

```
void DeTxtALista(Lista *l, FILE *f){
char auxGenero[15];
char auxColor[10];
Movie aux;
f=fopen("peliculas.txt","r");
if(f == NULL ) {
printf("No fue posible abrir el archivo\n");
}

fgets(aux.id, sizeof(aux.id), f);
fgets(aux.titulo, sizeof(aux.titulo), f);
fgets(aux.director, sizeof(aux.director), f);
fgets(auxGenero,(sizeof(auxGenero)), f);
if (strcmp(auxGenero, "Action") == 0){
aux.genero=Action;
}else if (strcmp(auxGenero, "Comedy") == 0){
aux.genero=Comedy;
}else if (strcmp(auxGenero, "Adventure") == 0){
aux.genero=Adventure;
}else if (strcmp(auxGenero, "Drama") == 0){
aux.genero=Drama;
}else if (strcmp(auxGenero, "Horror") == 0){
aux.genero=Horror;
}else if (strcmp(auxGenero, "SciFi") == 0){
aux.genero=SciFi;
}else if (strcmp(auxGenero, "Fantasy") == 0){
aux.genero=Fantasy;
}else if (strcmp(auxGenero, "Animation") == 0){
aux.genero=Animation;
}
fgets(aux.likes,(sizeof(aux.likes)), f);
fgets(aux.cantidad_votantes,(sizeof(aux.cantidad_votantes)), f);
fgets(aux.voto_promedio,(sizeof(aux.voto_promedio)), f);
fgets(aux.anio,(sizeof(aux.anio)), f);
fgets(aux.costo,(sizeof(aux.costo)), f);
fgets(auxColor,(sizeof(auxColor)), f);
if (strcmp(auxColor, "Color") == 0){
aux.color=Color;
}else if (strcmp(auxColor, "BW") == 0){
aux.color=BW;
}
Insertar(l, aux);


fclose(f);
}
```

Esta es la accion insertar:

```
void Insertar(Lista *l, Movie a){
Inicializar(l);
Lista *aux=malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));
aux->head->pelicula=a;
aux->head->next=l->head->next;
l->head->next=aux->head;
}
```

Y esta Inicializar:

```
void Inicializar(Lista *l){
l=malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));
}
```

Por ultimo estos son los tipos que nos dieron definidos, no los podemos cambiar:

```
//LSE de Movie
struct Nodo{
Movie pelicula;
struct Nodo *next;
};

//Puntero al primer elemento de la LSE
typedef struct{
struct Nodo *head;
}Lista;



//Arreglo de peliculas con cantidad
typedef struct{
Movie peliculas[SIZE];
int cant;
}Arreglo;
```

Variables:

FILE *archivo;

Lista *lista;

No encuentro el error,en realidad no me da error sino que cuando se ejecuta la accion DeTxtALista el cursor cambia a cargando y se termina la ejecucion al segundo, si alguien me puede ayudar, le agradezco!

.

Answer (score 1):

Esta función, aunque te pueda parecer lo contrario, **no hace nada**:

```
void Inicializar(Lista *l){
  l=malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));
}
```

Bueno, rectifico, sí que hace... crea fugas de memoria.

Se ve más facil si dejamos de usar punteros. ¿Qué valor tendrá `a` en el siguiente ejemplo?

```
void func(int a)
{ a++; }

int main()
{
  int a = 0;
  func(a);
  printf("%d", a); // Imprime 0
}
```

El programa, como no podía ser de otra forma, imprimirá 0 y la razón es que en `func` **estamos trabajando con una copia** de `a`, luego los cambios que realicemos en la copia se perderán al abandonar la función... pues con los punteros pasa exactamente lo mismo:

```
void func(int *a)
{ a++; }

int main()
{
  int a = 0;
  func((int*)a);
  printf("%d", a); // Imprime 0
}
```

Lo que hace `func` en este caso, es modificar la dirección a la que apunta **la copia de `a`**, luego la variable `a` original ni se entera.

Ahora bien, si en vez de modificar la copia del puntero, modificamos **la dirección de memoria que comparten** ambas variables, la cosa cambia:

```
void func(int *a)
{ *a++; }

int main()
{
  int a = 0;
  func(&a);
  printf("%d", a); // Imprime 1!!!
}
```

Pues bien, como en tu caso lo que pretendes es **modificar la dirección a la que apunta el puntero**, lo que necesitas son punteros dobles, en otro caso el cambio, como has podido ver, es meramente local:

```
void Inicializar(Lista **l){
  *l=malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));
}
```

Y, por supuesto, no olvides modificar las llamadas correspondientes.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, entendi y aplique los cambios necesarios pero el error sigue, lo que hize fue cambiar la funcion como sugeriste y la llamada de este modo:  Inicializar(&l);
Alguna idea por que el programa cierra cuando ejecuto la funcion DeTxtALista? Gracias igual

Comment: Modifique la funcion Insertar asi:
void Insertar(Lista **l, Movie a){
 Inicializar(&l);
 Lista *aux=malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));
 aux->head->pelicula=a;
 aux->head->next=l->head->next;
 l->head->next=aux->head;
}
Y me tira un error

Comment: Si le quito el ->head el error me dice Lista has no member named 'pelicula'.

Comment: disculpas por el tiempo perdido y gracias de todos modos por intentar ayudarme, como dices sera mejor que empiece a estudiar c mas a fondo